# Reconnection of Events to the Selected TabItem in WPF TabControl

Tags: wpf, charts, event-handling, wpf-controls

I developed a WPF Application that plots data from a file on a 2D Chart.
The user can zoom and pan, using the mouse.
Several drawings may be loaded into different Tabs of a WPF TabControl. The drawing itself is hold by a Grid within the TabItem.

Every time I am reading a file and generating the corresponding chart, I am also connecting the mouse events to the Grid that holds the Chart.

It happens that the mouse events turn to be connected to the last loaded chart, and when I select back any other TabItem, I have no control (zoom / pan) over it.

I did not find the way to reconnect the mouse events to the Grid in the TabItem I switched back to.

I would appreciate any cue.

Moti

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could connect an handler to the MouseEnter event of the grid. After that you could hook up the mouseevents.

on creation of the grid:

```
grid.MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter"
```

the MouseEnter handler:

```
private void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    if (grid == null)
        return;

    grid.MouseWheel += a1_MouseWheel;
}
```

the MouseWheel handler

```
private void a1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(grid.Name + " " + e.Delta);
}
```

I guess you remove the handlers from the grid's mouseevents !?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know whom to reconnect the events to. I don't disconnect the event handlers, but as soon as I connect them to other events (in a fresh TabItem), they disconnect from the previous ones.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I created a WpfApplication, put a button and a TabControl in the content, wired the button with a Click EventHandler, created a Grid within the Click EventHandler, wired the Grid.MouseWheel event to a EventHandler, added the Grid to the TabControl and displayed some Debug.WriteLine debugcode within the MouseWheel EventHandler. It works, event if I'm adding new TabItems and switch back to a further TabItem.

Comment: I am not sure that your application reeproduces the same conditions. In mine, there is a TabControl. In each TabItem, I define a Grid and connect Mouse events to it. Every newly created TabItem will react nicely to the events (zooming and panning the chart in the Grid within). However, when I select back an already existing TabItem, I find that the events were disconnected. The events are connected only to the last TabItem defined.

Comment: I don't think that the handler gets unhooked. A handler normally can be hooked on a few events. I'd guess that the mouseevents get handled by sime other ui control, maybe the tabitem itself. If that is the problem, you could hook the PreviewMouseWheel and put a breakpoint so see if that is the problem.

Comment: Well, Thank you, I would say that you put me back on track. I was looking in the wrong direction.